# Interpolate Multiseries Data In SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, interpolation, missing-data

I have a system that stores the data only when they are changed. So, the dataset looks like below.

| data_type_id | data_value | inserted_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 240 | 2022-01-19 17:20:52 |
| 1 | 30 | 2022-01-19 17:20:47 |
| 2 | 239 | 2022-01-19 17:20:42 |
| 1 | 29 | 2022-01-19 17:20:42 |

My data frequency is every 5 seconds. So, whether there's any `timestamp` or not I need to get the result by assuming in this 5th-second data value the same as the previous value.

As I am storing the data that are only changed, indeed the dataset should be like below.

| data_type_id | data_value | inserted_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 240 | 2022-01-19 17:20:52 |
| 1 | 30 | 2022-01-19 17:20:52 |
| 2 | 239 | 2022-01-19 17:20:47 |
| 1 | 30 | 2022-01-19 17:20:47 |
| 2 | 239 | 2022-01-19 17:20:42 |
| 1 | 29 | 2022-01-19 17:20:42 |

I don't want to `insert into` my table, I just want to retrieve the data like this on the `SELECT` statement.

Is there any way I can create this query?

PS. I have many `data_type`s hence when the OP makes a query, it usually gets around a million rows.

**EDIT**:
Information about server `Server version: 10.3.27-MariaDB-0+deb10u1 Debian 10`

The User is going to determine the `SELECT` *DateTime*. So, there's no certain `between` time.

As @Akina mentioned, sometimes there're some gaps between the `inserted_at`. The difference might be ~4seconds or ~6seconds instead of a certain 5seconds. Since it's not going to happen so frequently, It is okay to generate by ignoring this fact.

Comment: *Is there any way I can create this query?* Of course. Provide precise MySQL version info.

Comment: How to determine needed datetime range? from what and till what datetime value the table must be generated? What if some gap is not N*5 second (due to time detection accuracy, for example)?

Comment: @Akina I edited the question according to your questions.

Comment: Your edition does not answer on the question "How to determine needed datetime range?". You tell "The User is going to determine the SELECT DateTime." - does this means that the user have one definite datetime value and needs to determine the values at this moment?

Comment: @Akina thanks for the answer. The user draws a chart responding to this query. So, the user can draw the chart for 3 days or 1 week or 2 hours or 3 months, etc. They can determine the `date_time` as they like. So, you can consider the problem to be solved in a _Stored Procedure_ that takes the `data_type_ids`, `start_datetime` and `end_datetime` as **IN** parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of a query that gets you all the combinations of `data_type_id` and the 5-second moments you need, you can achieve the result you need using a subquery that gets you the closest `data_value`:

```
with recursive u as
(select '2022-01-19 17:20:42' as d
union all
select DATE_ADD(d, interval 5 second) from u
where d < '2022-01-19 17:20:52'),
v as
(select * from u cross join (select distinct data_type_id from table_name) t)
select v.data_type_id, 
(select data_value from table_name where inserted_at <= d and data_type_id = v.data_type_id
order by inserted_at desc limit 1) as data_value, 
d as inserted_at
from v
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=4fcf8154179c940b6ecb74cdbd9cd433)

You can replace the recursive CTE with any query that gets you all the 5-second moments you need.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE
cte1 AS ( SELECT @start_datetime dt
          UNION ALL
          SELECT dt + INTERVAL 5 SECOND FROM cte1 WHERE dt < @end_datetime),
cte2 AS ( SELECT *,
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY test.data_type_id, cte1.dt
                                    ORDER BY test.inserted_at DESC) rn
          FROM cte1
          LEFT JOIN test ON FIND_IN_SET(test.data_type_id, @data_type_ids) 
                        AND cte1.dt >= test.inserted_at )
SELECT * 
FROM cte2
WHERE rn = 1
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=380ad334de0c980a0ddf1b49bb6fa38e

Comment: There're two problems with this solution. **1.)** Although there's data on `2022-01-19 17:20:32` it creates a **timestamp** for `2022-01-19 17:20:35` that makes the solution harder to find the accurate time.
**2.)** I see that when I remove the `WHERE rn = 1` statement, it creates so many extra rows for even a short time period. In the case of looking for the closest `timepoint` looks very costly. I will try to adjust to solve this problem because it takes a very long time in case of a query for **one day** or longer...

Comment: @TaylanYuksel (1) I cannot understand what you tell about. Your sample data does not contain specified values. Edit the fiddle data, reproduce your issue, provide the link. (2) Add according condition to ON clause of cte2 which restricts the rows to some time range which oversizes max. possible gap with guarantee (for example, 5 minutes).

Comment: For the first point, I see that is my bad, I realized it's okay. For the second point, I applied your suggestion by restricting the rows for some time range. It got faster and created much less `rn`. However, the query speed is not convenient for this problem. The other answer gets it faster. I upvote yours as a useful answer as well. Thanks.